# publishProgress() causing crashes

Tags: java, android, compiler-errors, download

When I try to download a file the application crashes.
The problem is when i refresh progress bar. I used asynctask.Tthe error is into this:

```
while ((read = is.read(buffer, 0, 1024)) > 0) {

                    totalRead += read;
                    //System.out.println(totalRead);
                    String progress = ("" + ((int) (totalRead * 100)) / lenghtOfFile);
                    System.out.println(progress);
      /Here/      publishProgress(progress);

                    cos.write(buffer, 0, read);
                }
```

**LogCat:**

```
W/Bundle: Attempt to cast generated internal exception:
        java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
        at android.os.Bundle.getInt(Bundle.java:940)
        at com.android.server.am.MultiWindowManagerService.getDefaultWindowInfoLocked(MultiWindowManagerService.java:479)
        at com.android.server.am.MultiWindowManagerService.addWindowInfo(MultiWindowManagerService.java:317)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.startActivityLocked(ActivityStack.java:2394)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.startActivityUncheckedLocked(ActivityStack.java:3782)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.startActivityLocked(ActivityStack.java:3377)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.startActivityMayWait(ActivityStack.java:3946)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startActivity(ActivityManagerService.java:2651)
        at android.app.ActivityManagerNative.onTransact(ActivityManagerNative.java:148)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:1734)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:367)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
06-24 22:13:21.541    2271-2807/?                              W/Bundle: Key com.sec.android.multiwindow.DEFAULT_SIZE_H expected Integer but value was a java.lang.String.  The default value 0 was returned.
06-24 22:13:21.546    2654-2654/?                              W/ResourceType: Attempt to retrieve bag 0x01030068 which is invalid or in a cycle.
06-24 22:13:21.546    2271-2807/?                              W/Bundle: Attempt to cast generated internal exception:
        java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
        at android.os.Bundle.getInt(Bundle.java:940)
        at com.android.server.am.MultiWindowManagerService.getDefaultWindowInfoLocked(MultiWindowManagerService.java:483)
        at com.android.server.am.MultiWindowManagerService.addWindowInfo(MultiWindowManagerService.java:317)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.startActivityLocked(ActivityStack.java:2394)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.startActivityUncheckedLocked(ActivityStack.java:3782)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.startActivityLocked(ActivityStack.java:3377)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.startActivityMayWait(ActivityStack.java:3946)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startActivity(ActivityManagerService.java:2651)
        at android.app.ActivityManagerNative.onTransact(ActivityManagerNative.java:148)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:1734)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:367)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
06-24 22:13:21.546    2271-2807/?                              W/Bundle: Key com.sec.android.multiwindow.MINIMUM_SIZE_W expected Integer but value was a java.lang.String.  The default value 0 was returned.
06-24 22:13:21.551    2271-2807/?                              W/Bundle: Attempt to cast generated internal exception:
        java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
        at android.os.Bundle.getInt(Bundle.java:940)
        at com.android.server.am.MultiWindowManagerService.getDefaultWindowInfoLocked(MultiWindowManagerService.java:488)
        at com.android.server.am.MultiWindowManagerService.addWindowInfo(MultiWindowManagerService.java:317)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.startActivityLocked(ActivityStack.java:2394)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.startActivityUncheckedLocked(ActivityStack.java:3782)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.startActivityLocked(ActivityStack.java:3377)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.startActivityMayWait(ActivityStack.java:3946)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startActivity(ActivityManagerService.java:2651)
        at android.app.ActivityManagerNative.onTransact(ActivityManagerNative.java:148)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:1734)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:367)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
06-24 22:13:21.551    2271-2807/?                              W/Bundle: Key com.sec.android.multiwindow.MINIMUM_SIZE_H expected Integer but value was a java.lang.String.  The default value 0 was returned.
06-24 22:13:21.551    2271-2807/?                              W/Bundle: Attempt to cast generated internal exception:
        java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
        at android.os.Bundle.getInt(Bundle.java:940)
        at com.android.server.am.MultiWindowManagerService.getDefaultWindowInfoLocked(MultiWindowManagerService.java:492)
        at com.android.server.am.MultiWindowManagerService.addWindowInfo(MultiWindowManagerService.java:317)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.startActivityLocked(ActivityStack.java:2394)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.startActivityUncheckedLocked(ActivityStack.java:3782)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.startActivityLocked(ActivityStack.java:3377)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.startActivityMayWait(ActivityStack.java:3946)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startActivity(ActivityManagerService.java:2651)
        at android.app.ActivityManagerNative.onTransact(ActivityManagerNative.java:148)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:1734)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:367)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
```

Comment: The error is not there, can you show more of your asynctask?

Comment: Impossible... error is here!!!

Comment: can you just log cat `totalRead += read;` and after that write `Log.i(Tag,totalRead);` Just wanna see to make sure

Answer (score 0):

i guess you trying to change the UI (View elements) inside `doInBackground` you have to change it in `onPostExecute`

but only if you show the code of `publishProgress` we may find it for sure.

Comment: protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {

            mProgressDialog.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String unused) {

            dismissDialog(progress_bar_type);
            txt_percentage.setText("Stato Download: Completato!");

        }

Comment: `  protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {

            mProgressDialog.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String unused) {

            dismissDialog(progress_bar_type);
            txt_percentage.setText("Stato Download: Completato!");

        }`

Comment: @user2474478 if you have relevant code, post it in the question

Answer (score 0):

Seems that your async task uses `Integer` for publishing progress (the second generic type given to async task), you should change it to:

```
int progress = (int)((totalRead * 100) / lenghtOfFile);
```

or you can change the second generic type to be `String`.